# Method links do not exist - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-pagination

**I'm getting the following error:**

> Method links do not exist

I also tried render function which gives me the same result.

**This is my code:**

```
public function welcome() {
    $products = DB::table('products')->paginate(12);
    return view('welcome', compact('products', $products));
}
```

When I call `{{ $products->links() }}`, it shows an error but if I remove `{{ $products->links() }}` I can see the results.

This is my view:

```
    @foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <!-- Product item -->
        <div class="product-item hover-img">
            <a href="product_detail.html" class="product-img">
                <img src="images/default.png" alt="image">
            </a>
            <div class="product-caption">
                <h4 class="product-name"><a href="#">{!! $product->name !!}</a></h4>
                <div class="product-price-group">
                    <span class="product-price">{!! $product->price !!} KM</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="absolute-caption">
                <form action="{!! route('store') !!}" method="POST">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $product->name }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{ $product->price }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Dodaj u korpu">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

   {{ $products->links() }}
```

Comment: You need to use foreach to get all data from $products in your view

Comment: also you can return like this return view('welcome')->with('products',$products);

Comment: I'm using foreach loop its just I haven't posted it here

Comment: ok then where is the issue coming. Is it coming in controller due to paginate? You can remove paginate and then check if it works.

Comment: If I remove paginate I get all results in one page

Comment: try to use render() instead of links()

Comment: where is your pagination code?

Comment: Render shows Method render does not exist

Comment: ok ok links() must work. Checkout this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Eloquent` instead of query builder.

Use:

```
$products = \App\Product::paginate(12);
```

instead of

```
$products = DB::table('products')->paginate(12);
```

to make it work.

(Of course you need to have created `Product` model first extending Eloquent model)

Comment: Again I get the same result

Comment: @GoGo Try tu use also `compact('products')` instead of `compact('products', $products)`

Comment: Tried, I get the same thing

Comment: @GoGo Are you sure you are not overriding variable in view? Please show your view

Comment: @GoGo Are you sure you are using valid view? Because it seems as you used `get` method in controller instead of `paginate`